# Joining a row of data to multiple polygons (zip codes)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, attribute-joins, zip-codes

I received some data from a partner and was trying to do a visualization. I'm using ArcGIS / ArcMap 10.2

I have a table where each row (first column is the ID) represents a facility and all the US zip codes that intersect within a certain radius of that facility.

The zip codes are listed in a concatenated field, called "RSAComponents"
[image: Screencap]

What could I do to join shapefiles representing multiple associated zip codes to each row?

I suspect I could do some iteration via ModelBuilder, but I'm still a novice at using it.

Comment: To clarify, I already have a ZCTA file via [US Census / TIGER](https://www.census.gov/cgi-bin/geo/shapefiles/index.php) so I'm specifically wondering how I can perform a join that searches matching values in the two tables.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think there is a built-in tool in Arc to perform that type of operation. An operation, by the way, that is trivial to perform in some ETL software like FME. However, it could definitely be programmed with python and arcpy.

Comment: What kind of visualisation do you want to do? It would be possible to select all zipcodes for the first row, dissolve them into one geometry and join this to your table. Then do this for each row using arcpy. Will this be enough to do your visualization? What kind of table is it, excel?

Comment: Thanks - wanted to do a map book / Data Driven Pages style for a chloropleth/color shaded map with a page for each row. With Census I planned to join population data to each zip code and shade based on low-to-high population, for each facility. Yes the data is an Excel table right now. In another table, I have addresses of each facility (and can join based on the 1st column)